# jQuery sortable skip element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I use [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) function in my project. I need skip arrows(don't change arrow position) and change position of item1 with item2 for example and so on.

```
$('#approverChain').sortable({
        items: ':not(.static)',
        start: function(){
            $('.static', this).each(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.data('pos', $this.index());
            });
        },
        change: function(){
            $sortable = $(this);
            $statics = $('.static', this).detach();
            $helper = $('<div></div>').prependTo(this);
            $statics.each(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                var target = $this.data('pos');

                $this.insertAfter($('div', $sortable).eq(target));
            });
            $helper.remove();
        }
    });
```

Here is my all code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrshakirov/nh6e25s2/5/)

Comment: You probably can use the cancel option in order to make the .arrow not draggable. see http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel. But you'd probably better include arrows inside the sortable elements div (except the first one) and remove it if the dropped element has just become the first.